# how to connect outlook to c# in .net 5

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook

I created a class in .net 4.8 which works great.  I decided to move this to .net 5 and use it in a wpf project, but I can't seem to add the dll successfully. I have added a COM reference to the project of Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library (it has an identity of Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook).

When I try to add that to the using statement, the leading word Interop is flagged in red and tells me to add the using System.Windows.Interop;

OK, I did that and it looks like this:
using System.Windows.Interop;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

And it allows this line of code:
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

Problem now becomes oApp is not recognized to get a namespace, which I need to get a folder ... etc.

I would appreciate any guidance here on doing the correctly!

Answer (score 0):

You need to target .net framework up to 4.8, but not .net core. For example, the following runtimes are supported by the VSTO engine:

[image: VSTO wizard]

Comment: I am using .net 5.  But the problem is I didn't add all the class code from the class that works, so, stupid programming trick.  Thanks for the reply.